# Search web address from IP

Tags: google-chrome, ip, appdomain, bing

I have IP address aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd. How can I find website or domain name or website from just this IP address.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant [tag:ping], not [tag:bing].

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [IPLocationTools](https://www.iplocationtools.com) web application and look under the Hosted Domain section for all domain names found in one IP address.